# Haskell: Data.Set `notMember` slower then `notElem`?

Tags: haskell

I expect `f1` is *O(i²)* and `f2` is *O(i · log i)*. What is going on here?

```
import Data.Set

i = 20000

-- should be slow
f1 = [ x | x <- [1..i] , x `notElem` [2..i-1] ]
-- should be fast
f2 = [ x | x <- [1..i] , x `notMember` fromAscList [2..i-1] ]
```

ghci output:

```
*Main> f1
[1,20000]
(7.12 secs, 16,013,697,360 bytes)
*Main> f2
[1,20000]
(44.27 secs, 86,391,426,456 bytes)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just because optimizations haven't happened yet. If you put the following into a file `F.hs`:

```
module F (f1,f2) where

import Data.Set

-- should be slow
f1 :: Int -> [Int]
f1 i = [ x | x <- [1..i] , x `notElem` [2..i-1] ]
-- should be fast
f2 :: Int -> [Int]
f2 i = [ x | x <- [1..i] , x `notMember` fromAscList [2..i-1] ]
```

And compile it first with optimizations, you get the following:

```
$ ghc -O2 F.hs       # compile with optimizations
[1 of 1[ Compiling F            ( F.hs, F.o )

$ ghci F.hs          # now load it up in GHCi
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Ok, modules loaded: F (F.o)
Prelude F> :set +s
Prelude F> f1 20000
[1,20000]
(2.16 secs, 2,030,440 bytes)
Prelude F> f2 20000
[1,20000]
(0.05 secs, 4,591,312 bytes)
```

My guess is that in your situation you had GHCi recalculating `fromAscList [2..i-1]` multiple times, or something similar.

Comment: Because it's fun to see what changes are important, you can also try applying various optimizations by hand. From my experiments, the important two are lifting the definition of the set and making sure it's monomorphic. In ghci ```let s = fromAscList [2..i-1] :: Set Integer in [x | x <- [1..i], x `notMember` s]``` is instant, while ```let s = [2..i-1] :: [Integer] in [x | x <- [1..i], x `notElem` s``` is about twice as fast as OP's list-based code but still orders of magnitude slower than the `Set` version.

Comment: I believe it should be `ghci -fobject-code` in order to load the compiled version instead of interpreting. (of course you could have a `main` in the module, so it doesn't affect the answer)

Comment: @user2407038 I think if the object file file is already there the compiled version is loaded (at least that seems to be the case).

Comment: @DanielWagner answer is very useful to me.  The `let` gives the compiler the hint that `s` does not depend on `x`. Haven't seen things like that mentioned in Haskell books. Maybe I am reading the wrong books.